# NodeJS - Get live logs on webpage from server

Tags: node.js

Have a specific requirement in NodeJS where a webform (using Express) is submitted to the server application which makes ~50-100 API calls based on the form data. The whole process takes around 3-5 mins while the end user waits. Since the wait time is long, would like to show live logs after form submission.

Something like :

- Form data processing started...
- Created user...
- Assigned role to user....
- Connecting to friends of user...
- End of process. Request successfully completed...

Which would be the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate with the user at different points of time when the processing is going on:

- You could either send requests from the client-side periodically until
  the process is complete.
- OR you could set up 'reverse AJAX' using HTTP-Streaming with XHR
  objects or SSE - Server Sent Events.

Comment: Made it work with SSE from the server Anish. Thanks.